# How Do I Remove Link Hover From Images But Not Text?

Tags: html, css, image, hover, tumblr

I'm editing a Tumblr theme, and I have a very simple problem, this is the code for the links

```html
a {
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
a:hover {
    color:#000000;
    background:#ffffb3;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I want this to work **only for the text** but when you hover over the images on a photoset, the background becomes **yellow** too

[Screenshot: hover on photo, it becomes yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtSZI.png)

This is the code for the images

```html
img {
    border:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;    
    background-color: none;
}
```

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: Please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add a demo link also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work this:

```
.tumblr-box:hover {
    background: transparent;
}
```

But make sure the class `.tumblr-box` is on every image thumbnail and not on the text.

Comment: It worked, thank you!! Also, sarbaz, user966660 and faisal97 :)

Comment: Great. Please mark the correct answer as done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `CSS` to your code.

`img:hover{
    background-color:tranparent;
}`

Comment: It's not working, I added it and it's still there. `img, img:hover  {
    border:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;    
    background-color:tranparent;
}`

Comment: Yeh, Its never work in your case, because there is no <img> tag, the image is coming from tumblr, there is only a <a> tag. That's y, so please style your <a> tag class.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below CSS

```
.photo-data a.tumblr-box:hover {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.tumblr-box:hover { background: transparent; }
```

Which Text do you want to highlight?